# Postgresql load test scenarios

Tags: postgresql-10, postgresql-performance

I'm running a query in jmeter with 10 sessions I'm getting results faster.. but when the sessions are increased to 50 parallel sessions and the query was slower 5x times. Any suggestions.

Comment: Why do you think that increasing the number of parallel sessions would improve things? You are asking the database to do 5 times the work. Unless your hardware is prepared for that, it's no surprise that things are slowing down. Does your database server have 50 CPUs?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My db server has 16 vcpu. It runs on RDS .

Comment: I was not expecting a performance increase, was trying to understand if this is an expected behaviour